# c++ Window doesn't get created second time

Tags: c++, windows, registerclass

The code below creates the windows once, but when the function is called again, it fails to load the window. I want to make it so that I can get the same effect every time I call the function.

```
int nRandWidth = 150, nRandHeight = 15, nSpeed = 1;
int nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight;

LRESULT WINAPI MelterProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HDC hdcDesktop = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
        HDC hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);
        BitBlt(hdcWindow, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, hdcDesktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);
        ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdcDesktop);
        SetTimer(hWnd, 0, nSpeed, NULL);
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
    return 0;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        ValidateRect(hWnd, NULL);
        return 0;
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        HDC hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);
        int nXPos = (rand() % nScreenWidth) - (nRandWidth / 2),
            nYPos = (rand() % nRandHeight),
            nWidth = (rand() % nRandWidth);
        BitBlt(hdcWindow, nXPos, nYPos, nWidth, nScreenHeight, hdcWindow, nXPos, 0, SRCCOPY);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);
    }
    return 0;
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        KillTimer(hWnd, 0);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int ShiftPixels()
{
    nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    WNDCLASS wndClass = { 0, MelterProc, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), 0, NULL, L"Melter" };


    if (!GetClassInfo(GetModuleHandle(NULL), L"Melter", &wndClass))
    {
        if (!RegisterClass(&wndClass))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot register class!", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        }
    }
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Melter", NULL, WS_POPUP, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (!hWnd) return MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, L"Cannot create window!", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);

    srand(GetTickCount());
    MSG Msg = { 0 };
    while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT) {
        if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000)
            break;
    }
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    UnregisterClass(L"Melter", GetModuleHandle(NULL));
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ShiftPixels();
        Sleep(5000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**How can I modify the code above to make it run multiple times ?** I've Unregistered the windows class and destroyed the windows.

Comment: unrelated: Unless you are doing something really sneaky, `ShiftPixels` is a bad place to put a call to `srand`

Comment: @user4581301 I know, I shoud of called it in main. But that is the **"test"** code, so it will do !

Comment: You should call `GetLastError` when WinAPI function functions fail and inspect the value returned (this also implies checking returned values of all the WinAPI functions called, even such as `DestroyWindow`). Also if you don't want to erase background you should return `TRUE` when handling `WM_ERASEBKGND` to indicate that it has been erased.

Comment: @VTT I found out that the windows gets created every time, but the case `WM_TIMER` is invoked just once. What will cause it to be _true_ ?

Comment: You should check `SetTimer` result and inspect the value returned by `GetLastError` if it fails. And `WM_TIMER` won't be sent at 1ms intervals.

Comment: this is `C++` code so please remove the `c` tag

Comment: @user: I'm unable to see anything in the code that's valid C++, but not valid C. How did you conclude, that this is C++?

Comment: @IInspectable,  the title of the question specifically states this is C++ code.

Comment: regarding: `return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);`  this statement only gets executed if NONE of the switch/cases are taken.  Suggest adding a `default:` case and placing that statement in the default case.  Then send messages to this function that are NOT any of the other cases.

Comment: regarding: `srand(GetTickCount());` this should only be executed once in the whole program,  Suggest placing early in the `main()` function.

Comment: the function: `ShiftPixels()`  calls several functions that can return an error indication.  When such error occurs, after handling the error, cleanup and exit the program.

Comment: every function that can return an error indication should have the returned value checked to assure the function was successful.  When ever not successful, handle the error, then exit

Comment: @user: That may well be the case. And yet, you specifically said *"this is `c++` **code**"*. I don't see any C++ in that code.

Comment: @VTT I don't fully understand a thing, would you mind explaining it to me: Why, even though I do create the timer when the windows is created, and I do remove it when the windows is destroyed, second time when I run the function, the VM_TIMER message doesn't get send to the window !